# What is famous-gl ?

Tags: javascript, famo.us

In a lot of of codepen samples of Famo.us I see people including famous-gl references for rendering things, but I cannot find which library is to be referenced to use it nor I can find any documentation on it can someone guide me in the correct direction ?

Comment: also need to know what is famous-scene and is there anyplace where I can find documentation for it.

Comment: famous-gl, famous-scene are libraries abandoned quickly in the beta release.  As far as I know, not valid any longer.

Comment: oh too bad :( is there anything which equivalent to them and can be used along with famo.us

Comment: Famo.us will be releasing their new `MixedMode` version that will be WebGL and DOM and other anouncements at [jQuerySF](http://jquerysf.com/) is what they are saying.

Comment: @talves thanks, looking forward to mixed mode :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed: this will be part of mix-mode to be released.